# Chrome and Firefox give different results json for( key in result)

Tags: jquery, json, firefox, google-chrome

I have this code:

```
$.get('http://mapit.mysociety.org/areas/'+ulo, function(response) {

                        console.log(response);

                        var areaList = [];

                        for (var k in response) {
                                 var obj = response[k];
                                 areaList.push(obj);
                                 console.log(response[k]);

                            }
                        var len = areaList.length;
```

In Chrome, it works great, for example, change +ulo to wembley.

On the Chrome Dev Tool, I get the object as per the two console.log's under the heading object:

> Object
>    index_fb.js:41
>   [
>   Object
>   all_names: Object
>   codes: Object
>   country: "E"
>   country_name: "England"
>   generation_high: 18
>   generation_low: 1
>   id: 8258
>   name: "Wembley Central"
>   parent_area: 2488
>   type: "LBW"
>   type_name: "London borough ward"
>   **proto**: Object

But, same in firefox and i get this in the Firebug:

> {"8258": {"parent_area": 2488, "generation_high": 18, "all_names": {}, "id": 8258, "codes": {"ons": "00AEHE", "gss": "E05000104", "unit_id": "11458"}, "name": "Wembley Central", "country": "E", "type_name": "London borough ward", "generation_low": 1, "country_name": "England", "type": "LBW"}}

index_fb.js (line 41)

{

index_fb.js (line 48)

"

index_fb.js (line 48)

8

index_fb.js (line 48)

2

index_fb.js (line 48)

5

index_fb.js (line 48)

8

index_fb.js (line 48)

"

index_fb.js (line 48)

:

index_fb.js (line 48)

index_fb.js (line 48)

{

index_fb.js (line 48)

"

index_fb.js (line 48)

p

index_fb.js (line 48)

a

index_fb.js (line 48)

r

index_fb.js (line 48)

e

index_fb.js (line 48)

n

index_fb.js (line 48)

t

index_fb.js (line 48)

_

index_fb.js (line 48)

a

index_fb.js (line 48)

r

index_fb.js (line 48)

e

index_fb.js (line 48)

a

index_fb.js (line 48)

"

index_fb.js (line 48)

:

index_fb.js (line 48)

index_fb.js (line 48)

2

index_fb.js (line 48)

4

index_fb.js (line 48)

8

index_fb.js (line 48)

8

index_fb.js (line 48)

, etc etc

So, the Console.log(response) is right, but it seems to take every letter in the:

```
for (var k in response) {
```

k = numbers in firefox, where as in chrome, it deals with k as a whole number 8258.

How do I get around this so it works on both ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the new code:  Still the same issue:

```
$.get('http://mapit.mysociety.org/areas/'+ulo, function(response)  {

                        console.log(response);

                        var areaList = [];

                        for (var k in response) {

                            if (response.hasOwnProperty(k)) { 
                                 var obj = response[k];
                                 areaList.push(obj);
                                 }
                            }
```

I have also tried, but do I need to wrap the Get into a $.ajax to ensure it knows a json is returned.  The app has an issue with using ajax to a none secure source.

So far no joy :(

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry but i am not sure i understand that ?

Comment: Just a suggestion: whenever you perform for-in with javascript wrap the inner part in if (obj.hasOwnProperty...
In your case it would be:
for (var k in response) {
   if (response.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      // logic
   }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox considers your object to be a string. You should specify `dataType:"json"` to retrieve a proper JSON object, which properties you will be able to enumerate. Jquery allows you to set the dataType through the final parameter of `$.get` :

```
$.get(url,successFunction,"json")
```

Comment: How would I do this with a .get statement ?

Comment: I used $.getJSON, thou when i used this a few weeks ago, it kept giving me an error due to HTTPS to HTTP etc.

Comment: I added the syntax in my answer, you can also take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/